# module which generated a bad name for a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a module which have used the name "log" for one of its internal methods.

The problem is, that this module has an "extend self" line.  If I call this module in a script as well as load the rails environment, everytime the keyword "log" is used (i.e Rails.application.config.paths.log, or config.paths.log) the method inside that module is getting invoked instead of what the original file was looking for.

Is there a way to do a MyModule.module_eval and somehow rename the method name and route all the local calls inside that module that called "log" into the new method?

Otherwise Rails and this module don't play nice together.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you simply re-name the method in your module?

Comment: the module isn't mine.  But if it's still possible to rename it, please do tell me how!!! I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer.  I privatized the bad method inside the module using module_eval

```
NoSoSmartModule.module_eval do
  private :log
end
```